# .htaccess url rewriting help just first line works

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Please can someone help me with `.htaccess` solution as I can not work it out.

I am trying to obtain nice urls using following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\.htm yellow.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\.htm blue.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\.htm green.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Unfortunately, only the first line works.

If I try this - all works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\-yellow.htm yellow.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\-blue.htm blue.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\-green.htm green.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Ideally, I would like to have shorter URLs so `.htm`or just virtual folder style `/name/` would be great.

thank you all in advance for your help (this is my first ever dynamic site and I learned a lot already from all of you here)

Comment: U must need different identifier for different files else htaccess only get the ist rule

Comment: thank you @devpro. 

is there a way I can give the same rule for yellow, blue and green together ?

Comment: I have no idea. R u using any framework?

Comment: no any framework. just simple .php files with mysql queries that i created on my own and database from which data are pulled, that's all.

Comment: Just a suggestion one page for all three colors like page.php?color=green or yellow or blue

Comment: What kind of values will u get in name=$1

Comment: well i can try to fit all in one page.php. 
however, yellow, blue and green are completely different categories which use different tables and queries so i am not sure it is pratical..will try anyway, thx for your help and time @devpro

Comment: name=$1 is name_unique for each row of data for that particular item

Comment: But u r going good.. this was my suggestion. .